# Enforcing Strict Type Checking in Transpiled TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript to write a Node.js module. However, my worry is that my transpiled code is completely unsafe once imported and used by a non-TypeScript project. Are there any compiler options to build in strict type checking?

In other words, consider this class...

```
class Foo {
  readonly product: number;

  constructor(public readonly foo: number, public readonly bar: number) {
    this.product = foo * bar;
  }
}
```

Which TypeScript complies as:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(foo, bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.product = foo * bar;
    }
}
```

Within my TypeScript project, if I try this:

```
const test1 = new Foo(10, 2);
const test2 = new Foo('dogs', 'cats');
```

TypeScript nicely complains about the second one... beautiful. However, if the transpiled code is run in a plain JS project, it's perfectly happy with either... though `test2` now contains a dangerous `test2.product` property (`NaN`), where a valid number is expected.

What I'd like is some TS compiler option that writes this JS code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(foo, bar) {
        if (typeof foo !== 'number') {
            throw new TypeError(`Argument of type '${foo}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`);
        }
        if (typeof bar !== 'number') {
            throw new TypeError(`Argument of type '${bar}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`);
        }
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.product = foo * bar;
    }
}
```

I routinely put this sort of code when writing in non-TS JavaScript, but TypeScript actually flags these lines as redundant (which, within the confines of TypeScript, they are). However, the are critical when the code is run without the TS safety net. So, my worry is that using TS is actually undermining the type-safety of the final code that will actually be run in the actual project it's used in.

Are there any best practices or compiler settings for TS when the primary target will be use in non-TypeScript projects?

Comment: Typescript does not flag this as an error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=5&pln=4&pc=13#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoDNEC5oA7AVwFsAjAUwCcBuDbaCsGw0y2hzbABxvgATEsAAu7ctRqNsweEQiiaI0fBoAKPPAmcaAGmasdUgJQoZTLAEsc0daICevKvFtboAQgC8X6AHIOKT8zNB5LS1EACwEAd2IqOIAVJyoAURoBDQADAEEaAHNyKiJRaFdoR2d-ABJkLQBfP2grGCJ4UsgIK3yiMAoQKgqkXlYwMipRWjLbSsGAyVo-ADosk25wrHqLSxs7WfKWGk8ff0DFkO2Niuj4OKIE6GTndMz1XIKikumKlJrkQ8azVa7WgnW6vX6g1U0BGNDGEym5VmpwWNGWq3WGy2YQikRaS3cvi0mPCUXxh2gvkOJNx+P4QhUlNwiGgACpDPRttj6kA You probably have some eslint/tslint flagging this.

Comment: Yah... I am looking at one right now, and it's not raised from TS or ESLint... It looks like it's a WebStorm setting.

Comment: That said, writing such checks into TypeScript code does feel redundant. The whole point (well... one big point) of TypeScript should be to eliminate this type of tiresome boilerplate from source code and let the compiler add it in. I have been looking through TS compiler options and just don't see anything that would do this. So, perhaps this is more of a feature request.

Comment: It would be a feature request doomed to failure. TS only checks JS, they never insert extra code based on types, and don't change the semantics of valid JS.  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Comment: Got it! I'll prob continue to write my own type checks where passing the wrong type could lead to serious and uncaught bugs lurking in the code. It does underline my grumble with TypeScript... that it doesn't fundamentally change the failings of JS itself and make it into a proper typed language. It helps, but still a far cry from using a proper typed language the that guarantees such bugs are caught promptly at compile time and prevent runtime issues.